# Converting negative numbers

Tags: go

When converting a negative number to an unsigned integer and later adding that value it results in subtracting.

```
a := (uint8)(10)
b := (int8)(-8)
fmt.Println(a + (uint8)(b)) // result: 2
```

Is this an idiomatic approach or should it be done more explicitly?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for using `uint8` and `int8`? Their use is typically considered [unidiomatic](https://tour.golang.org/basics/11) in Go: “*The `int`, `uint`, and `uintptr` types are usually 32 bits wide on 32-bit systems and 64 bits wide on 64-bit systems. When you need an integer value you should use `int` unless you have a specific reason to use a sized or unsigned integer type.*”

Comment: @MTCoster yes, because I'm sending packets over a network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the type is unsigned it is an [**overflow**](https://play.golang.org/p/DyxKn8TrS4r):
`uint8(b)` is `248`, so `a + uint8(b)` is `10+248=258=> 255 0 1 2 => 2`

> my question is more about how to subtract from unsigned integers when
> the value (sometimes you want to add and sometimes subtract) is coming
> from an argument (that must be a signed type) which makes it so that
> you have to do type conversion before subtracting/adding.

Using both `int8`:

```
    a := int8(10)
    b := int8(-8)
    fmt.Println(a + b) // 2
    fmt.Println(a - b) // 18
```

You may avoid the overflow, like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/yFsXC8m-nt-):

```
    a := uint8(10)
    b := int8(-8)
    c := uint8(b)
    d := uint16(a) + uint16(c)
    fmt.Println(d) // 258
```

---

You should remove superfluous parentheses here:

> a := (uint8)(10)
> b := (int8)(-8)
> fmt.Println(a + (uint8)(b))

Use this:

```
a := uint8(10)
b := int8(-8)
fmt.Println(a + uint8(b))
```

---

See:
[confusion about convert `uint8` to `int8`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55719813/confusion-about-convert-uint8-to-int8)

Comment: It doesn't matter if the type is `uint8` or `uint32`, you can try.

Comment: Anyways, my question is more about how to subtract from unsigned integers when the value (sometimes you want to add and sometimes subtract) is coming from an argument (that must be a signed type) which makes it so that you have to do type conversion before subtracting/adding.

Comment: "You may using both int8" - the value I'm subtracting/adding to must be `uint16`. The original post gives me the wanted result, I am looking for a more idiomatic way (because it looks like a hack).

Comment: No it's not a hack, this is the way to go ( idiomatic way). So be it, and use `uint16`